# Prolog, вопрос по поиску с возвратом.

Tags: поиск, рекурсия, prolog

Такой вопрос: Вот использую я рекурсивный поиск с возвратом, и хотел бы запомнить результат каждого найденного решения(например занести в список), что бы потом эти результаты как то проанализировать. Как я могу это организовать?

Просто вся проблема в том, что когда мы находим одно из решений и записываем результат(в тот же список), нас, так как это поиск с возвратом, возвращает на ту часть, где возможно пере доказать правило, и того списка, в который мы занесли результат решения, как бы еще и нет... Сразу на ум приходит фраза "Нужна глобальная переменная", и тут то программисты с алгоритмическим складом ума уходят в печаль, ведь в Прологе нет глобальных переменных... Но как же тогда быть?

Кстати, использую PDC prolog.

Comment: Можно набирать список в процессе поиска, примерно как [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/156668/prolog-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: список набирается, я говорю о каком то конечном анализе этого списка(1), и занесении результата этого анализа, в какой новый список(2). Тот старый список(1) в результате поиска с возвратом пере набирается и получается список(3), и нужно снова его проанализировать и занести результат в список (2).

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема тогда? Вообще, не видя проблемный кусок кода, трудно посоветовать что-то определенное.

Comment: Проблема в том что бы список (2) всегда существовал, и дополнялся в результате доказательств и передоказательств

Comment: @Djonny, все еще не вижу кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В  чем собственно заключается вопрос. Пролог поддерживает механизм создания бд. Глобальную переменную можно  заменить отношением состоящим из одного картежа(
facts number

single pi(integer)

clause

pi(0).

test(....):-....  !,asserta(pi(.....)),.....fail.

test().

Comment: вообще вас не понял

Comment: Не пробовали  стандартный предикат Findall. Которым всегда возможно собрать список из фактов. Факты возможно добавить  во время поиска с возвратом.Вот готовый список.